# Ĉu iu ajn uzas pronomojn verbe?

Tags: verbs, pronouns, abbreviations

Do, mi ofte mallongigas salutojn. Plejparte homoj komprenas "sal," sed kio pri "mias Elikjo" anstataǔ "mi estas Elikjo?"

Answer (score 1):

Jes, kelkaj parolantoj uzas pronomojn verbe, kun la signifo: aparteni al la persono(j) difinita(j) de la pronomo:

```
Tio miis, vi ne estus devinta ĝin preni!

Se tiu domo mius, mi farbus ĝin tute malsame
```

Comment: Notu, nenio trafo de "mias" aŭ "mius" en [Tekstaro](https://tekstaro.com), do verŝajne tre granda plejparto ne komprenas tiujn vortojn.

Comment: @JuhaMetsäkallas mi demandis en listo de familioj kun denaskuloj: kelkaj uzas "mias" kaj ĉiuj (en kunteksto) komprenas ĝin. Notu ke mi nur respondis la originalan demandon, tio ne igas tiun uzon dezirinda. Mia teorio: same kiel "ĝi estas alta" iĝas "ĝi altas", "tio estas mia" iĝas "tio mias" (memoru ke temas pri denaskuloj, kiuj ne lernas la lingvon kiel ni). Tio rekte, regule, enkondukas "mius", "miis", kion ni (nedenaskuloj) nur povas analizi kiel "mi-as".

Answer (score 0):

Teorie, laŭ la uzado de kelkaj verkistoj avangardaj, la personaj pronomoj ja povas esti uzataj verba-maniere, kun verbaj finaĵoj, sed kun la aparta senco jena, kiu estas poseda : la afero mias = la afero estas mia, laŭ la pli generala modelo de verbigo de ĉiuj ajn adjektivoj : la afero bluas = la afero estas blua.

Sammaniere, la pronomoj korelativaj povas esti verbigitaj laŭ la modelo plej regula, kun senco kvalita aŭ maniera  : la afero tias = la afero estas tia = la afero havas tiun kvaliton, aŭ okazas sammaniere.  Ekzemple : la vetero en marborda Italio estas varmega kaj seka en somero kaj ne tro malvarma sed tre malseka en vintro, tias (= tia estas) ankaŭ la vetero en marborda Kalifornio.

Oni do povus, teorie, laŭlogike, uzi la verbon ti-i kun la senco de "do" en la angla.  Ekzemple : Li manĝas pli rapide ol ŝi tias (He eats faster than she does : tias = manĝas rapide).  Mi manĝas kias li = Mi manĝas kia li estas (kiam li manĝas) = Mi manĝas samaspekte, sammaniere kiel li.  Mi ias verkisto = Mi estas ia verkisto = mi estas iu-maniere verkisto.  Mi ĉias verkisto = Mi estas verkisto en ĉiu ĝenro, ĉiu-maniere.  Mi nenias verkisto = Mi estas nenia verkisto = Mi absolute ne estas verkisto.